# Error in QGIS with Raster Tool in plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

When I open QGIS I get the following error:

Couldn't load plugin 'rastertool' due to an error when calling its `classFactory()` method and the following command:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrsgis' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\rastertool\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .RasterTool import RasterTool
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 744, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\rastertool\RasterTool.py", line 54, in 
    from pyrsgis.convert import rastertocsv
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 744, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrsgis'


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.10.1-A Coruña A Coruña, ef24c526da 

Python Path:
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\leastcostpath
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python37.zip
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\aderyn
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\aderyn
```

I have seen that a lot of people have faced similar problems. 
I downloaded OSGeo4W Network installer 64 bit. The last version of QGIS.

How can I solve this?

---

I ran the command but I got the following error:

[image]

Do you know something about it?

---

@SaijinNaib's answer worked, however when I open QGIS I got another error:

Couldn't load plugin 'rastertool' due to an error when calling its `classFactory()` method

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visvis'
```

Do you know how to solve this as well?

Also why do I have so many errors?

Comment: It appears that you asked a second and third question. Please keep your questions focused on a single question. It is always advisable to open another question rather than adding another question as an edit to the original.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the pyrsgis python module, which must be required by that plugin.

Please execute either CMD, PowerShell, or Windows Terminal as Admininstrator.
Ensure QGIS is completely closed.

CD into the OSGeo4W python environment (`C:\OSGEO4W\apps\Python37\`)

```
CD C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37
```

[image]

Issue the following python/pip command to install pyrsgis:

```
.\python.exe -m pip install pyrsgis -U
```

[image]
Re-Launch QGIS and it should work, provided there are no other missing dependencies.

---

In response to your additional information above:
You are also missing OpenSSL for Windows.

Please install this build from here (x64):
https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_1_1d.exe

Link to VirusTotal scan:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/181cbdd92da74cf4b55ccfdfe24533a2bf67822a96a530cb23b51da52446e32e/detection

Once you have it installed, please re-follow my instructions from above.

---

In response to another missing module, yes, this process is generally applicable to manual installation of python modules into the OSGeo4W python environment under Windows. As noted above, the key value is the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MODULENAME'` . Substitute the MODULENAME for the module named after `.\python.exe -m pip install`.

Comment: Dear Saijin thanks a lot!! It worked, however when I open QGIS I got another error:

Couldn't load plugin 'rastertool' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visvis'

Sorry for it. Do you know how to solve this as well? Also why do I have so many errors?

Thanks again!

Comment: Dear Saijin, I followed the same methodology for visvis and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you were able to get things sorted out. I'll update my answer to include a clause about the general applicability of this workflow for manual installation of python libraries in OSGeo4W. Please upvote/accept the answer if it met your needs.